# AWS CloudFormation - Creating Layer Version and Function that uses layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-lambda, yaml

I have a Cloudformation template that currently looks roughly like the following.

```
Resources:
  MyLayer:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs12.x
        - nodejs10.x
      Content: ../layers/nodejs/
      LayerName: myLayer
      ### etc...
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    DependsOn: MyLayer
    Properties:
      Code: lambdas/my-lambda.js
      Description: A lambda that makes use of MyLayer
      FunctionName: myLambda
      Handler: my-lambda.handler
      Layers: !Ref CommonLayer
      ### etc...
```

The core idea here is I want to create a new LayerVersion and have the Lambda update to this latest LayerVersion on every deployment. I am having trouble inserting MyLayer's Arn into MyLambda's Layer property. Here is what I have tried:

1. !Ref CommonLayer which I saw returns the Arn based on this [CloudFormation Cheatsheet](https://theburningmonk.com/cloudformation-ref-and-getatt-cheatsheet/). I get a failure when creating the stack at the creation of MyLambda (output shows MyLayer has been successfully created) saying: "Value of property Layers must be of type List of String"
2. !GetAtt CommonLayer.Arn however this function is just not supported for Layers/ the return value does not have an Arn field.

Is this a YAML syntax type problem or is my goal of creating a Layer and then a Lambda that depends on said Layer not possible in one Cloudformation template?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Value of property Layers must be of type List of String

*Layers* must be a *List*. You’ll have to replace:

```
  MyLambda:
    Properties:
      Layers: !Ref CommonLayer
```

With this:

```
  MyLambda:
    Properties:
      Layers:
      - !Ref CommonLayer
```

Hope that helps :)